# trying to get the day date in interpolation from array of date objects

Tags: angular

trying to get the day date in interpolation from array of date objects but it gives me only one digit when I use `day.getDay()`

like for day 13 of the month it shows 3

```
  monthsDays = []


  ngOnInit() {
    const getDaysInMonth = (month, year) => (new Array(31)).fill('').map((v, i) => new Date(year, month - 1, i + 1)).filter(v => v.getMonth() === month - 1)
    this.monthsDays = getDaysInMonth(new Date().getMonth() + 1, new Date().getFullYear())
    console.log(this.monthsDays[12])
  }
```

```
            <div class="calendar owl-carousel owl-theme">
              <div *ngFor="let day of monthsDays" class="item">{{day.getDay()}}</div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.getDate()`

`.getDay()` returns the day of the week.

Get Date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate

Get Day: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Comment: okaay, stupid mistake :)
thanks

Comment: No worries. I've spent countless minutes and hours figuring out mistakes :)